# ValueError: unsupported hash type md5

Tags: python, celery, hashlib

i write a python c extension to implement PEP302 to define my own meta_path hook and path hooks, so that i can load encrypt python modules

// c extension code http://pastie.org/private/c2tslasqg6omph2i88oug

i modify site.py(python -c "import site;print site.__file__") , append two line:

```
sys.path.append('/opt/pycode-encrypt')
import hacksite
```

// hacksite code http://pastie.org/private/epfsnfgz7fwhdwavtqxvw

now the problem:
when i use original code to start celery worker, all is fine.
but when i encrypt code with my extension, then i start celery worker with --autoreload, i got some error:

```
[2016-05-24 16:01:20,709: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ValueError('unsupported hash type md5',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 206, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 374, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 278, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 821, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/loops.py", line 41, in asynloop
    obj.controller.register_with_event_loop(hub)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 218, in register_with_event_loop
    description='hub.register',
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 155, in send_all
    fun(parent, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/autoreload.py", line 60, in register_with_event_loop
    w.autoreloader.register_with_event_loop(hub)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/autoreload.py", line 286, in register_with_event_loop
    self.on_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/autoreload.py", line 282, in on_init
    self._hashes = dict([(f, file_hash(f)) for f in files])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery-3.1.18-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/autoreload.py", line 81, in file_hash
    hobj = hashlib.new(algorithm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 128, in __hash_new
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
```

but in python interactive mode, i can import _hashlib and i can run _hashlib.new('md5', 'msg') without error.
error just happends in celery worker with --autoreload params

i also give some test and i found:
i modify /usr/bin/celery to add some test code try to use _hashlib.new and is ok.
but the same code in `celery/worker/autoreload.py#file_hash` raise ValueError .

i'm new to python c extension develop, and i work for this problem for a while, i can't find some thing useful to solve this problem.

so i came here to ask for help.

thank you

Comment: did you figure this out? similar problem for me